# How do I create a daily time series using data that isn't taken daily

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a csv file that is written like this

```
Date        Data
1/5/1980    25
1/7/1980    30
2/13/1980   44
4/13/1980   50
```

I'd like R to produce something like this

```
Date        Date
1/1/1980    
1/2/1980
1/3/1980
1/4/1980
1/5/1980    25
1/6/1980 
1/7/1980    30
```

Then I would like R to bring the last observation forward like this

```
Date        Date
1/1/1980    
1/2/1980
1/3/1980
1/4/1980
1/5/1980    25
1/6/1980    25
1/7/1980    30
```

I'd like two separate data.tables created one with just the actual data, then another with the last observation brought forward.

Thanks for all the help!

Edit: I also will need any NA's that are populated to changed to 0

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

- create a data.frame with successive date
- merge it with your original data.frame
- use `na.locf` function from `zoo` to carry forward your data

Here is the code. I use lubridate to work with date.

```
library(lubridate)
df$Date <- mdy(df$Date)
successive <-data.frame(Date =  seq( as.Date(as.yearmon(df$Date[1])), df$Date[length(df$Date)], by="days"))
```

`successive` is the vector of successive dates. Now the merging:

```
result <- merge(df,successive,all.y = T,on = "Date")
```

And the forward propagation:

```
library(zoo)
result$Data <- na.locf(result$Data,na.rm = F)


          Date Data
1   1980-01-05   25
2   1980-01-06   25
3   1980-01-07   30
4   1980-01-08   30
5   1980-01-09   30
6   1980-01-10   30
7   1980-01-11   30
8   1980-01-12   30
9   1980-01-13   30
10  1980-01-14   30
11  1980-01-15   30
12  1980-01-16   30
13  1980-01-17   30
14  1980-01-18   30
15  1980-01-19   30
16  1980-01-20   30
17  1980-01-21   30
18  1980-01-22   30
19  1980-01-23   30
20  1980-01-24   30
21  1980-01-25   30
```

---

The data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Date        Data
                 1/5/1980    25
                 1/7/1980    30
                 2/13/1980   44
                 4/13/1980   50", header = T)
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants (exactly). The `Date` needs to start from the first of the month, not the `min(Date)`

Comment: @Sotos yep didn't see that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  complete(Date = seq(as.Date(format(min(Date), "%Y-%m-01")), max(Date), by = "day")) %>%
  fill(Data) %>%
  replace(., is.na(.), 0)
```

First 10 rows:

```
# A tibble: 104 x 2
   Date        Data
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 1980-01-01     0
 2 1980-01-02     0
 3 1980-01-03     0
 4 1980-01-04     0
 5 1980-01-05    25
 6 1980-01-06    25
 7 1980-01-07    30
 8 1980-01-08    30
 9 1980-01-09    30
10 1980-01-10    30
```

I've used as a starting point the 1st day of the month and year of minimum date, and maximum the maximum date; this can be of course adjusted as needed.

EDIT: @Sotos has an even better suggestion for a more concise approach (by better usage of `format` argument):

```
df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  complete(Date = seq(as.Date(format(min(Date), "%Y-%m-01")), max(Date), by = "day")) %>%
  fill(Data)
```

Comment: I am literally 38 seconds late :D. FYI, you can add `-01` in `format` and thus not have to paste. This is what I did, `complete(df, Date = seq(as.POSIXct(format(min(Date), format = '%Y-%m-01'), format = '%Y-%m-%d'), max(Date), by = 'day')) %>% fill(Data)`

Comment: Hehe, oh believe me very familiar to me :-) Thanks for the tip, will add it! Quite cool, didn't know the `format` accepts this kind of arguments.

Comment: Otherwise this is a very thin line, you could as well turn this into your answer.. If you do, I'll delete it

Comment: Nahh... It's first come first served and our method is exactly the same

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I should have also added. I'm going to need all the NA's that are populated to be replaced with a 0. Its going to be used in another script I wrote, but it won't handle NA's well. (I'll add this to the main question as well)

Comment: You're welcome, check my edit if this suits your needs

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the result should start at the first of the month of the first date and end at the last date and that the input data frame is `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, convert `DF` to a zoo object `z`, create a grid of dates `g` merge them to give zoo objects `z0` (with zero filling) and `zz` (with na.locf filling) and optionally convert back to data frames or else just leave it as is so you can use zoo for further processing.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF, header = TRUE, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
g <- seq(as.Date(as.yearmon(start(z))), end(z), "day")

z0 <- merge(z, zoo(, g), fill = 0)  # zero filled
zz <- na.locf0(merge(z, zoo(, g)))  # na.locf filled

# optional
DF0 <- fortify.zoo(z0)  # zero filled
DF2 <- fortify.zoo(zz)  # na.locf filled
```

### data.table

The question mentions data tables and if that refers to the data.table package then add:

```
library(data.table)

DT0 <- data.table(DF0) # zero filled
DT2 <- data.table(DF2) # na.locf filled
```

### Variations

1. I wasn't clear on whether the question was asking for a zero filled answer and an `na.locf` filled answer or just an `na.locf` filled answer whose remaining NA values are 0 filled but assumed the former case. If you want to fill the NAs that are left in the `na.locf` filled answer then add:

   ```
   zz[is.na(zz)] <- 0
   ```
2. If you want to end at the end of the last month rather than at the last date replace `end(z)` with `as.Date(as.yearmon(end(z)), frac = 1)` .
3. If you want to start at the first date rather than the first of the month of the first date replace `as.Date(as.yearmon(start(z)))` with `start(z)` 
   .
4. As an alternative to (3), to start at the first date and end at the last date we could simply convert to `ts` and back.  Note that we need to restore `Date` class on the second line below since `ts` class cannot handle `Date` class directly.

   ```
   z2.na <- as.zoo(as.ts(z))
   time(z2.na) <- as.Date(time(z2.na))
   zz20 <- replace(z2.na, is.na(z2.na), 0)     # zero filled
   zz2 <- na.locf0(z2.na)                      # na.locf filled
   ```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
Date        Data
1/5/1980    25
1/7/1980    30
2/13/1980   44
4/13/1980   50"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```